# strange behaviour with wine emulator, multithreading and C stdio

Tags: c, windows, wine

I've the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>

int main() {
    /* DWORD WINAPI */void input(/* LPVOID */void* lpParam) {
        Sleep(1000);
        printf("hello mingw!\n");
        // return 0;
    }
    _beginthread(input, 0, NULL);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I cross-compile from ubuntu 22.04.01 with mingw-w64 with:

...$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o example.exe example.c

In a native Win7 box it works as expected:

```
...$ example.exe
hello mingw! (after 1 second)
a
...$
```

but in wine when entering 'a' from keyboard, the 'a' climbs up one line:

```
...$ example.exe
aello mingw!
...$
```

It seems as if printf output from a thread didn't update console cursor. This only happens when read code (getchar()) executes before the write code (printf), hence the Sleep.

Any pointers?

Comment: Is that a function nested in `main()`?

Comment: @Haris gcc supports nested function as an extension.

Comment: @Jabberwocky That's news to me. Thank you.

Comment: Because we must always write non-standard code just for the heck of it. Thanks gcc.